# Can anyone share the documentation of itk and vtk for python 3.5

Tags: python-3.5, vtk, itk

I need some documentation related to itk and vtk for python  3.5 for my learning process.so, any help would be appreciated..Thank you.

Comment: this question is not about coding itself, therefore doesnt belong here

Answer (score 0):

See the [ITK Python Quick Start Guide](https://itkpythonpackage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Quick_start_guide.html).

Comment: But the itk latest version missing of itkvtkglue functions

Comment: You have to compile and build VTK then ITK and under the advanced build options in cmake ensure that the ITKVTKglue is selected when building ITK. It is there but you need to select it as it is not a default build option

Comment: On Windows and Linux, it is now possible to `pip install itk-vtkglue`.